# When printing the model summary for a CNN model, the input layer is a garbage integer. Also, the trained model has 96% error

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a  model that recognizes static gestures using CNN. I have 26 gestures and 2400 images for all gestures. However, the model has a missing input layer and has a 96% error.

I am pretty new so have no idea about most of the things. I have tried changing some things to no help.

///this is my model

```
def cnn_model():
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    filepath="cnn_model_keras2.h5"
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    #checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint1]
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    return model, callbacks_list

/// training and testing

model, callbacks_list = cnn_model()
    model.summary()
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=20, batch_size=500, callbacks=callbacks_list)
    scores = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)
```

I expect at most 20% loss but the loss is 96%. Also,

expected model summary:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb7a0.jpg

what I got:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxGxl.jpg

This is my first question on any forum so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might track this strange bug here : [keras plot_model inserts strange first input row containing long integer number #11376](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11376)

It looks like an open issue in Keras. Maybe check your version.